# Getting error while operating multiple windows in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am doing operation on 3 window.Using select window command in robot framework I will travels to 1st child window and in same way on 2nd child window.But after completion of task on 2nd window it will close automatically and then if I used select window for selecting again 1st window it will shows following error

Error:

"NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found"

Code:

```
@{Window_list} =  Get Window Names
Select Window   @{Window_list}[1]
#Do some Operations On 1st window
#Launch Second window 

@{Window_list} =  Get Window Names
Select Window   @{Window_list}[2]
#Do some operations on 2nd window
#Save the changes on 2nd window it will close 2nd window automatically

Select Window   @{Window_list}[1]...........#fails at this keyword
```

If anyone has solution on this please mention.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I do not know exactly the reason, but I've met this case and solved by using [Run Keyword And Ignore Error](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Erro).

In your case:

```
Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Select Window   @{Window_list}[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its not working.it executed that keyword but not select that window

Comment: @Sujit Patil: Could you give me the content of the next error message? Please use "Get Location" after "Select Window" to make sure that "Select Window" do not work. Thanks.

Comment: After completion of my operation on 3rd window it will automatically close so any keyword like select window or Get location is doesn't work and gives following error
"NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed from unknown error: web view not found"